# change android package name using command line

Tags: android, ant, package, command-prompt

I am developing android applications using command line on windows 7 by writing script in .bat file. I just double click that ".bat" file and  my source get compiled and app gets ready for release. Now, I want to change package,application label and logo by using same command prompt or .bat file releasing multiple applications against the same source.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the command to change the application icon and etc.. . but you can run the linux commands in android

using Runtime.getRunTime().excute() method

Please have a look at this api class [Runtime](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html)